# How to prevent Matlab from hanging entire system? Disable swapping

Tags: matlab, memory, freeze

It is very easy to hang entire system with Matlab. It is sufficient to run any operations on very large matrices to do this.

In hang situation Matlab is apparently neither give the system to work and nor works itself. I.e. this "operation mode" is completely useless and harmful.

Is it possible to disable Matlab from jumping over it's head? Is it possible to disable/minimize swapping or something?

It would be much better if Matlab just fail to complete an operation than if it is simulating some work which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

This guide outlines a few strategies that you can put to use

http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Comment: Do you think the question was very informative? It was very generic. You can hang any programming environment not just Matlab by running memory intensive or computationally intensive work. I thus provided at least a reference so that you have a place to start looking for a solution